# Aggregate functions on a 3-level pandas grupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a new df with simple metrics like mean, sum, min, max calculated on the Value column in the df visible below, grouped by ID, Date and Key.

| index | ID | Key | Date | Value | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 655 | 321 | 2021-01-01 | 50 | 546 | 235 | 252345 |
| 1 | 675 | 321 | 2021-01-01 | 50 | 345 | 345 | 34545 |
| 2 | 654 | 356 | 2021-02-02 | 70 | 345 | 346 | 543 |

I am doing it like this:

`final = df.groupby(['ID','Date','Key'])['Value'].first().mean(level=[0,1]).reset_index().rename(columns={'Value':'Value_Mean'})`

I use .first() because one Key can occur multiple times in the df but they all have the same Value. I want to aggregate on ID and Date so I am using level=[0,1].

and then I am adding next metrics with pandas merge as:

`final = final.merge(df.groupby(['ID','Date','Key'])['Value'].first().max(level=[0,1]).reset_index().rename(columns={'Value':'Value_Max'}), on=['ID','Date'])`

And I go like that with other metrics. I wonder if there is a more sophisticated way to do it than repeat it in multiple lines. I know that you can use .agg() and pass a dict with functions but it seems like in that way it isn't possible to specify the level which is important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[655,655,655,675,654], 'Key':[321,321,333,321,356], 
                  'Date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-02-02'],
                   'Value':[50,30,10,50,70]})
print (df)
    ID  Key        Date  Value
0  655  321  2021-01-01     50
1  655  321  2021-01-01     30
2  655  333  2021-01-01     10
3  675  321  2021-01-01     50
4  654  356  2021-02-02     70
```

---

```
final = (df.drop_duplicates(['ID','Date','Key'])
           .groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg(Value_Mean=('Value','mean'),
                                                       Value_Max=('Value','max')))
print (final)
    ID        Date  Value_Mean  Value_Max
0  654  2021-02-02          70         70
1  655  2021-01-01          30         50
2  675  2021-01-01          50         50

final = (df.groupby(['ID','Date','Key'], as_index=False)
           .first()
           .groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg(Value_Mean=('Value','mean'),
                                                       Value_Max=('Value','max')))

print (final)
    ID        Date  Value_Mean  Value_Max
0  654  2021-02-02          70         70
1  655  2021-01-01          30         50
2  675  2021-01-01          50         50

df = (df.groupby(['ID','Date','Key'], as_index=False)
      .first()
        .groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False)['Value']
        .agg(['mean', 'max'])
        .add_prefix('Value_')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    ID        Date  Value_Mean  Value_Max
0  654  2021-02-02          70         70
1  655  2021-01-01          30         50
2  675  2021-01-01          50         50
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work correctly. Value_Mean uses ID column and Value_Max Date column while all calculations should be made on Value column.

Comment: @overb it is weird, because `Value_Mean=('Value','mean')` means use column `Value`, aggregate mean an create column `Value_Mean`. So not understand how is used ID column?

Comment: Yes, it is but still that is the case. Check with this df: `pd.DataFrame({'ID':[655,675,654], 'Key':[321,321,356], 'Date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-02-02'], 'Value':[50,50,70]})`

Comment: Ok, I can do it like that `df.groupby(['ID','Date','Key'], as_index=False).first().groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg({'Value':['sum', 'min', 'mean']` and it works but then I miss the information about ID and Date and I need to have those columns too.

Comment: @overb - seems you have some old pandas version, added solution for it. All soluton working and return same ouput. answer was edited.

Comment: That's probably correct. I'm using 1.0.5 because of some dependencies. The second solution works like a charm. Thank you a lot for your assistance and for time you spent on it!